# Python tkinter Game Collisions

Tags: python, tkinter, collision

I'm having trouble getting the ball to react to the paddles and the walls correctly. The right paddle controlled by the arrow keys and the ball both move as intended, but the left paddle doesn't move at all.
The ball is supposed to bounce off the top and bottom walls and the paddles. It currently bounces off the side walls and ignores the paddles.
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle_1, paddle_2, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle_1 = paddle_1
        self.paddle_2 = paddle_2
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_left = False
        self.hit_right = False

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos_1 = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle_1.id)
        if pos[0] <= paddle_pos_1[1] and pos[1] <= paddle_pos_1[0]:
            if pos[2] >= paddle_pos_1[3] and pos[2] <= paddle_pos_1[3]:
                return True
            return False
        paddle_pos_2 = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle_2.id)
        if pos[3] >= paddle_pos_2[1] and pos[1] <= paddle_pos_2[3]:
            if pos[2] >= paddle_pos_2[0] and pos[2] <= paddle_pos_2[0]:
                return True
            return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 1
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.hit_right = True
        if pos[2] <= 0:
            self.hit_left = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

class Paddle_First:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 10, 100, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 450, 200)
        self.y = 0
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.go_up)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Up>', self.go_nowhere)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', self.go_down)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Down>', self.go_nowhere)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.y)

    def go_up(self, evt):
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] < 0:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            self.y = -3

    def go_down(self, evt):
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[3] > self.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            self.y = 3

    def go_nowhere(self, evt):
        self.y = 0

class Paddle_Second:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 10, 100, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 50, 200)
        self.y = 0
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-W>', self.go_up)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-W>', self.go_nowhere)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-S>', self.go_down)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-S>', self.go_nowhere)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.y)

    def go_up(self, evt):
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] < 0:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            self.y = -3

    def go_down(self, evt):
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[3] > self.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            self.y = 3

    def go_nowhere(self, evt):
        self.y = 0

def game():
    w = 0
    v = 0
    canvas.delete(button_window)
    timer1 = time.time()
    while 1:
        if ball.hit_right == False and ball.hit_left == False:
            ball.draw()
            paddle_1.draw()
            paddle_2.draw()
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if ball.hit_left == True:
            v = 1
            break
        if ball.hit_right == True:
            w = 1
            break
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_text(250, 150, font="Arial 70", text="Game Over")
    if w == 1:
        canvas.create_text(250, 300, font="Times 48", text='Left Wins!')
    if v == 1:
        canvas.create_text(250, 300, font="Times 48", text='Right Wins!')

root = Tk()
root.title("Game")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

canvas.pack()
root.update()

paddle_1 = Paddle_First(canvas, 'blue')
paddle_2 = Paddle_Second(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle_1, paddle_2, 'red')

button_start = Button(master=None, font="Times 80", text="Start?", command=game)
button_window = canvas.create_window(250, 100, anchor=N, window=button_start)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but Tkinter binding needs you use the evt in your functions, and you aren't using evt in your functions.

```
def go_up(self, evt):
    if evt.keysym == 'Up':
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] < 0:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            self.y = -3

def go_down(self, evt):
    if evt.keysym = 'Down':
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[3] > self.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            self.y = 3

def go_nowhere(self, evt):
    if evt.keysym == 'Up' or event.keysym == 'Down':
        self.y = 0
```

Comment: Since the binding is explicitly on the "Up" key, the only way that `go_up` will be called is when the "up" key is pressed. Therefore, it's no necessary to check the keysym.